# How do you set the ContentUrl of Attachments generated by a Form in the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, facebook-messenger, botframework

I want to send a carousel of images with buttons from my bot on Facebook Messenger.

How do I set the **ContentUrl** and **ContentType** of **Attachments** generated by a **Form** in the Microsoft Bot Framework?

I can do this manually when creating a Message object:

[C# Code, JSON Response and Messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PASQC.png)

```
var reply = message.CreateReplyMessage();
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

var actions = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action>();

actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action
{
    Title = "Small",
    Image = @"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png",
    Message = "Small"
});

actions.Add(new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action
{
    Title = "Large",
    Image = @"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png",
    Message = "Large"
});

reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
{
    Title = "Flat White",
    Actions = actions,
    ContentUrl = @"http://imgur.com/XbCCntC.png",
    ContentType = "image/png"
});
```

But I don’t know how to do it when using a Form. I can use the **DescribeAttribute** to set the Image URL of an Action, which shows up in the JSON response.

But that doesn’t do/display anything, and I think the image needs to be a part of the Attachment object not the Action anyway.

[Partial C# Code, JSON Response and Messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9CKa.png)

```
public enum WhiteStyle
{
    Invalid = 0,
    [Describe(Image = @"http://imgur.com/XbCCntC.png")]
    FlatWhite,
    [Describe(Image = @"http://imgur.com/qbbi6yc.png")]
    Latte,
    [Describe(Image = @"http://imgur.com/sF95Vsc.png")]
    Cappuccino
}
```

Comment: Please add your code in-line, and not as a link to an image.